# Different results for same output

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion, subvalues

In a power series solution method, I  am trying to find the roots of an equation. By changing the parameters I need to get the roots. The problem is the parameter value is provided as 0.15 which gives some result that is different from the value 15/100. I am not sure which one is correct. Can you help me out?

Comment: Please share a *minimal* example featuring Mathematica code that potential respondents can copy, paste and study in their own notebook sessions in order to suggest solutions.

Comment: Substitute the solution back into the equation to determine if it in fact satisfies the equation.